# C# how to show a \n character in a string if the new line is empty

Tags: c#, string, character

```
using System.Linq;

namespace BowlingPins
{
    public class Bowling
    {
        public string BowlingPins(int[] arr)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string pins = "!!!I!!!\n!!I!I!!\n!I!I!I!\nI!I!I!I";
            string[] pinArr = pins.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < pinArr.Length; i++)
            {
                string item = pinArr[i];
                if (item == "I")
                {
                    count++;
                }

                foreach (int num in arr)
                {
                    if (num == count)
                    {
                        pinArr[i] = "!";
                    }
                }
            }
            
            var result = string.Join("", pinArr.Reverse()).Replace("!", " ");
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

So the code works fine its just when it spits out the string if the end(s) newlines of the string are empty it doesn't show the \n character and I need it to.

Its displaying something like this
"I I I I\n I I I---whitespace-----"
and I want
"I I I I\n I I I \n---whitespace-----\n---whitespace-----"

Comment: \r\n instead? use that or Environment.NewLine

Comment: Could you perhaps post what output you're getting and what you're expecting? I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around what is being asked here.

Comment: Do you mean you need to actually see a '\' character followed by a 'n'?  If so you need to to start with a verbatim string `@"!!!I!!!\n!!I!I!!\n!I!I!I!\nI!I!I!I"` or delimit the backslashes `"!!!I!!!\\n!!I!I!!\\n!I!I!I!\\nI!I!I!I"`.  If you mean it isn't displaying 4 lines then it depends on how you're displaying the result and @Ctznkane525 comment might help.

Comment: Try testing your logic here https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7EyYt or show us the input and what you expect for the output

Comment: FYI you could just work with a `char` array instead of creating a bunch of single character strings with `var charArray = pins.ToCharArray();`